# more lines in list <ul> and vertical centers alignment

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a list of items (such as ul) with texts in more than one line in some items. All texts, regardless of how many lines I have should be centered vertically. Please see example where "+" and "=" signs are not in the centers.

```
.menu ul{
  display: flex;
  }

  .menu li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>Water <br> pressure <br> and volume</li>
  <li>+</li>
  <li>Pot <br> temperature</li>
  <li>=</li>
  <li>Something <br> difficult</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

[Example of improper behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ltfc46u/1/).

Is there some easy solution for such text alignment (I'd like to avoid using divs/grids, etc.)?

Thank you!
Marcin

Comment: So, do you want your list on multiple line? These are in single line all now.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the desired end result? Bear in mind that, semantically, your current HTML doesn't seem to make any sense, and will - inevitably - be problematic for people using screen readers.

Comment: Neil helped me already (cannot accept the answer in the next 9 minutes:). Desired outcome (based on Neil's answer): https://jsfiddle.net/7Ltfc46u/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
align-self: center;
```

on the li-Tags, if I understood you right.

Comment: This one works too and seems to be more powerful (no issues with margins in the future).

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li{
  margin:auto 0;
}
```

the margin top and bottom on auto will center every li verticaly.